# Bash looping through files in Directory

Tags: bash, loops

I have a bash script, created by someone else, that I need to modify a little.
Since I'm new to Bash, I may need a little help with some common commands.

The script simply loops through a directory (recursively) for a specific file extension.
Here's the current script: (runme.sh)

```
#! /bin/bash
SRC=/docs/companies/

function report()
{
    echo "-----------------------"
    find $SRC -iname "*.aws" -type f -print
    echo -e "\033[1mSOURCE FILES=\033[0m" `find $SRC -iname "*.aws" -type f -print |wc -l`
    echo "-----------------------"
exit 0
}

report
```

I simply type **#./runme.sh** and I can see a list of all files with the extension of .aws

My primary goal is to limit the search.  (some directories have way too many files)
I would like to run the script, limiting it to just 20 files.

Do I need to place the entire script into a loop method?

Answer (score 1):

That's easy -- as long as you want the first 20 files, just pipe the first `find` command through `head -n 20`. But I can't resist a little cleanup while I'm at it: as written, it runs `find` twice, once to print the filenames and once to count them; if there are a lot of files to search, this is a waste of time.  Second, wrapping the actual content of the script in a function (`report`) doesn't make much sense, and having the function `exit` (rather than `return`ing) makes even less. Finally, I like to protect filenames with double-quotes and hate backquotes (use `$()` instead). So I took the liberty of a bit of cleanup:

```
#! /bin/bash
SRC=/docs/companies/

files="$(find "$SRC" -iname "*.aws" -type f -print)"
if [ -n "$files" ]; then
    count="$(echo "$files" | wc -l)"
else # echo would print one line even if there are no files, so special-case the empty list
    count=0
fi

echo "-----------------------"
echo "$files" | head -n 20
echo -e "\033[1mSOURCE FILES=\033[0m $count"
echo "-----------------------"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `head -n 20` (as proposed by Peter). Additional remark: the script is very inefficient, as it runs `find` twice. You should consider using `tee` to gennerate a temporary file when the command runs for the first time, count the lines of this file afterwards and delete the file.

Answer (score 0):

I would personnaly prefer to do it like this:

```
files=0
while read file ; do
    files=$(($files + 1))
    echo $file
done < <(find "$SRC" -iname "*.aws" -type f -print0 | head -20)

echo "-----------------------"
find $SRC -iname "*.aws" -type f -print
echo -e "\033[1mSOURCE FILES=\033[0m" $files
echo "-----------------------"
```

If you just want there count, you could only use `find "$SRC" -iname "*.aws" -type f -print0 | head -20`