# How can I run a bash script on all files with a json extension in a directory?

Tags: bash, directory

I need to convert a bunch of json files to CSV with the script I have. These files are in a cloned Github repo and thus, there are multiple folders in the directory that have json files in them. The script needs to go through all the folders and convert the json files. How can I do this?

I've tried

```
for FILE in `ls /Users/user.name/Desktop/cloned_git_repo/*json`; do ./json_convert.sh
$FILE; done
```

However, it returns

```
ls: /Users/user.name/Desktop/cloned_git_repo/*json: No such file or directory.
```

Any help would be appreciated as this would make my life 1 million times easier. Note: I'm on a mac.

Comment: [BashPitfall #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash looping through files in Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681781/bash-looping-through-files-in-directory)

Comment: Try `find /path/to/repo -name "*.json" -exec ./json_convert.sh {} \;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to avoid iterating over the output of `ls`, as its output may vary from system to system. Try using `find`

```
find . -type f -name "*.json" | xargs ./json_convert.sh
```

Or, if your script only takes one argument at a time:

```
find . -type f -name "*.json" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file
do
    ./json_convert.sh "$file"
done
```

Comment: `xargs` has `-n1` option to take one argument at a time. By default `xargs` inteprets quotes and spaces and such, you want `xargs -d $'\n'`. Or `-print0 | xargs -0`